# removing a node from a certain position and moving to the end of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm still new to this language, so bear with me.

I'm trying to unlink a node from its `next` and `previous` nodes and move it to the end of the list, and relink the nodes that were around the node that was removed.

I have this function to do the unlinking and relinking, but I'm wondering if my initial `while` loop doesn't do the trick.

Edit: reposted code below

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const string face[] = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                        "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" }; 
const string suit[] = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades" };

int nmax = 4;

string random_card(bool verbose=false) {
    string card;

    card = face[ rand()%13 ];
    card += " of ";
    card += suit[ rand()%4 ];

    if (verbose)
      cout << card << "\n";

    return card;
}

class list{
    struct node{
        node(int index = 0);
        int index;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
    };
    public:
        list();
        ~list();
        void insert(int i);
        int numNodes;

    private:
        node *head;
        
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const list &v);
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, const list &v){
    list::node *printer = v.head->next;
    while(printer != NULL){
        os << face[printer->index] << " ";//now you can call list in cout << list and it will print whole list;
        printer = printer->next;
    }
    return os;
}

list::list(){
    head = new node;
}

list::node::node(int index_1){
    index = index_1;
    next = NULL;
    prev = NULL;
}

list::~list(){
    delete head;
}

void list::insert(int i){

    node *tracker = head;
    node *last = head;

    while(tracker->next != NULL){
        tracker = tracker->next;
        if(tracker->index == i){
            (tracker->prev)->next = tracker->next;
        }
    }

    if(head->next == NULL){
        node*newNode = new node;
        newNode->index = i;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        head->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = head;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        numNodes = numNodes + 1;
        return;
    }

    else{
        node*newNode = new node;
        newNode->index = i;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        while(last->next != NULL){
            last = last->next;
        }
        last->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = last;
        numNodes = numNodes + 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    bool verbose = false;
    int seedvalue = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
      string option = argv[i];
      if (option.compare(0,6,"-seed=") == 0) {
        seedvalue = atoi(&argv[i][6]);
      } else if (option.compare("-verbose") == 0) {
        verbose = true;
      } else 
        cout << "option " << argv[i] << " ignored\n";
    }
    srand(seedvalue);
    list array[4];
    list v;
    int num = 0;
    int counter = 13;
    
    while(array[num].numNodes != counter){
        string card = random_card(verbose);
        stringstream ss;
        ss << card;
        string facer, suiter, buffer;
        ss >> facer >> buffer >> suiter;
        
        if(suiter == suit[0]){
            num = 0;
        }
        if(suiter == suit[1]){
            num = 1;
        }
        if(suiter == suit[2]){
            num = 2;
        }
        if(suiter == suit[3]){
            num = 3;
        }
        
        for(int x = 0; x < 13; ++x){
            if(facer == face[x]){
                array[num].insert(x);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << setw(8) << suit[i] << " : " << array[i] << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hi, perhaps step through it?

Comment: well that's what the first while loop is doing right? I'm relinking while i go through

Comment: jspcal  means step through with a debugger

Comment: can you please post all code so we can test it out

Comment: Tactical note: the function name `insert` does not describe *node from its next and previous and then move it to the end of the list and then relink the nodes that were around the node that was removed* very well. I'd expect it to put a node somewhere in a list without moving anything.

Comment: echoing @user4581301 comment. Please explain *exactly* what the result of this insert function is supposed to be

Comment: future bug: `while(tracker->next != NULL)` will fail  if `tracker` is `NULL`. Usually a loop like this will be `while(tracker != NULL)` and the `tracker = tracker->next;` will happen last.

Comment: We've got all the code now. That's a good start. We can reason about the program behaviour a bit better, but the intended behaviour of the code is still a bit murky. Recommendation: back up the code and then remove everything that's not needed to reproduce the bug. That means all of the randomization goes. You build a list that you know has problems and then call the function that has the problem with an appropriate parameter to expose the problem. Use [mre] for inspiration. Often you'll find that removing places for bugs to hide is all you need to do to find the bug.

Comment: I have the index of the node constructor set to 0 for the index of the node so I don't think a node can be NULL even if it's the head.

Comment: Another good linked list trick is to draw pictures. Draw the list before, all of the steps you need to perform to transform the list, and draw what it looks like afterward. Then follow your code exactly, stepping through the function with a debugger to see what really happens helps a lot here, and try to draw the same pictures. If you can't, you'll prbably see where you deviated and need to make a change.

Comment: Future bug: `list::~list(){ delete head; }` deletes the first node in the list and only the first node. The rest of the nodes are leaked.

Comment: The linked list doesn't have the capability yet, but if you add the ability to remove nodes later you'll have trouble knowing when to stop, and if you remove all of the nodes, you won't be able to insert again.

Comment: I won't be removing nodes just need to move one to the end. I'm trying the debugger now. I'm pretty certain the problem is that I'm not moving the current node to the end of the list when the index matches. I've tried every which way to do that, but it never adds any more cards after a certain number or it prints out a half made list.

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert()` is not fully un-linking/re-linking nodes.  Once it finds a node to remove, it re-links only that node's previous node, but not its next node, or the list's `head` if the node being removed is the 1st node in the list.

Try something more like the following instead. Make life easier for yourself by breaking up functionality into more manageable and task-appropriate pieces:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const string faces[] = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                        "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" }; 
const string suits[] = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades" };

struct playingCard {
    int face;
    int suit;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const playingCard &card);

playingCard random_card() {
    playingCard card;
    card.face = rand() % 13;
    card.suit = rand() % 4;
    return card;
}

class list{
    struct node{
        node(int face, node *prev = NULL, node *next = NULL);
        int face;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
    };

    public:
        list();
        ~list();
        void insert(int face);
        void remove(int face);
        int getNumNodes() const;

    private:
        node *head;
        int numNodes;

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const list &v);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const playingCard &card) {
    os << faces[card.face] << " of " << suits[card.suit] << "\n";
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const list &v){
    list::node *printer = v.head;
    while (printer){
        os << faces[printer->face] << " ";
        printer = printer->next;
    }
    return os;
}

list::node::node(int face, node *prev, node *next)
    : face(face), prev(prev), next(prev)
{
}

list::list()
    : head(NULL), numNodes(0)
{
}

list::~list(){
    while (head){
        node *next = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = next;
    }
}

int list::getNumNodes() const {
    return numNodes;
}

void list::insert(int face) {

    // if you really want to MOVE an existing node to a new
    // position in the list, it would be trivial to add an
    // unlink() method to unlink and return that node rather
    // than destroy it.  But your node is so trivial to begin
    // with, this doesn't really matter one way or the other...

    //node *removed = unlink(face);
    remove(face);

    node **end = &head, *last = NULL;
    while (*end) {
        last = *end;
        end = &(last->next);
    }

    /*
    if (removed) {
        removed->prev = last;
        *end = removed;
    }
    else
    */
        *end = new node(face, last);

    ++numNodes;
}

void list::remove(int face) {
    node *tracker = head;
    while (tracker) {
        if (tracker->face == face) {
            if (tracker->prev) tracker->prev->next = tracker->next;
            if (tracker->next) tracker->next->prev = tracker->prev;
            if (tracker == head) head = tracker->next;
            delete tracker;
            --numNodes;
            return;
        }
        tracker = tracker->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    bool verbose = false;
    int seedvalue = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        string option = argv[i];
        if (option.compare(0,6,"-seed=") == 0) {
            seedvalue = atoi(argv[i].substr(6).c_str());
        }
        else if (option == "-verbose") {
            verbose = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "option " << argv[i] << " ignored\n";
        }
    }

    srand(seedvalue);
    list array[4];
    int suit = 0;
    
    while (array[suit].getNumNodes() < 13){
        playingCard card = random_card();
        if (verbose) cout << card;
        array[card.suit].insert(card.face);
        suit = card.suit;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        cout << setw(8) << suits[i] << " : " << array[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```